# Record Unity audio clip in mono

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the code below to record an audio clip using my computer's built-in microphone in unity.

This is working fine, however, I need the audio clip to record in mono with just 1 channel of audio rather than in stereo.

I wondered if there is a way to tell unity to record in mono, or to convert the clip to mono after it has recorded?

```
      public void StartRecord()
    {
        AudioSource audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audioSource.clip = Microphone.Start(selectedDevice, false, 300, 44100);
        Debug.Log("the selected device is" + selectedDevice);
        recordedAudioClip = audioSource.clip;
        startRecordingTime = Time.time;
}
```

The following is used to stop the recording:

```
public AudioClip StopRecord()
    {
        

        //Trim the audioclip by the length of the recording
        AudioClip recordingNew = AudioClip.Create(recordedAudioClip.name,
            (int) ((Time.time - startRecordingTime) * recordedAudioClip.frequency), recordedAudioClip.channels,
            recordedAudioClip.frequency, false);
        float[] data = new float[(int) ((Time.time - startRecordingTime) * recordedAudioClip.frequency)];
        recordedAudioClip.GetData(data, 0);
        recordingNew.SetData(data, 0);
        this.recordedAudioClip = recordingNew;
        
        
        return recordedAudioClip;
        //Play recording
        //audioSource.clip = recordedAudioClip;
        //audioSource.Play();
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you set number of channels to 1 in AudioClip.Create(..)?

Comment: If I set the number of channels to 1 then the recording plays back half the speed, so it can't be understood. (If you listen back to the audio it is heard at half-speed, when I convert the recorded audio to text it just returns null)

Comment: Try dividing the frequency by 2 as well (all instances of freq).

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Is it possible for me to specify that it takes just the right channel of recordedAudioClip.channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting an audio clip to mono requires the following steps:

1. Get the number of channels the source audio has
2. Construct an array for the data that is the source length divided by the channel count
3. Loop through the source data, starting at the channel index you want to sample, on each iteration skip (n) samples, where (n) is the source channel count.
4. Assign the data to the audio clip

The below function takes in an audio clip and attempts to convert it to mono using the specified channel.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts an audio clip to mono
/// </summary>
/// <param name="srcAudioClip">Source audio clip</param>
/// <param name="channelIndex">The source channel to sample from</param>
/// <returns>A mono audio clip</returns>
private AudioClip GetMonoAudioClip(AudioClip srcAudioClip, int channelIndex)
{
    var channelCount = srcAudioClip.channels;
    if (channelCount <= channelIndex)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Invalid channel index for conversion.  Index must be below {channelCount}.");
        return null;
    }

    var monoAudioClip = AudioClip.Create(
        $"{srcAudioClip.name}-MONO",
        srcAudioClip.samples / channelCount, 1,
        srcAudioClip.frequency, false
    );

    var srcData = new float[srcAudioClip.samples];
    var monoData = new float[monoAudioClip.samples];

    if (!srcAudioClip.GetData(srcData, 0))
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Unable to get data from source audio clip!");
        return null;
    }

    for (int i = channelIndex; i < srcData.Length; i += channelCount)
    {
        monoData[i / channelCount] = srcData[i];
    }

    monoAudioClip.SetData(monoData, 0);

    return monoAudioClip;
}
```

Let me know if you have any problems with this.  I tested using a random stereo audio track I have, however the clip itself has virtually the same L/R tracks making it difficult to test the channel index portion of my code.  This should technically work with any number of channels, eg. stereo, 5.1, etc.